# Python crashes when updating QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I am using a QAbstractItemModel to wrap a class which is essentially a python dictionary.

The item model is just there so that then I can use the QTreeView.

When I create my QTreeView, I instantiate my wrapper with an instance of my dictionary, I then instantiate an ItemModel to wrap it. (The basis of this wrapper is here: https://github.com/spanners/pyqt4-examples/blob/master/treeview.py)

When my dictionary changes, I emit a signal, and the ItemModel picks up the signal. I won't know exactly what changed, so I go through the nodes in my ItemModel, if they don't match what's in my dictionary, I add or remove nodes until they match. Then I emit dataChanged with the root node as that start_index and then end index at -1,-1.

Most of the time this works just fine.

But occasionally I get a dreaded Python.exe crash as if I accessed a widget from the wrong thread.

It seems to be particularly likely if I am trying to edit a value through the TreeView when the model below is being updated.

Is there something I should be doing to make it safe to change the model while there is an active editor delegate?

What other things should I be watching out for....or does someone have a better idea how I should have done this to begin with?

Comment: Is this code with which you have problems?

Comment: You should call [`beginInsertRows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) before inserting rows and `endInsertRows` afterwards.

Comment: Found my problem, I fell into a classic python pitfall...I meant to go through a node creation algorithm only if there were no children in my node...so I had a for loop with an else, turns out this means I was recreating all my nodes all the time by accident!